# How to improve my current method of generating an audio transcript from an online video

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, sox, youtube-dl, pocketsphinx

I am working on a project that needs to download and analyze online videos. Most of the videos are hosted on YouTube but some are hosted on Facebook.

My task is to generate an audio transcript for every video.

My colleague was using a series of programs sequentially given some `{link}`:

```
youtube-dl -f '(mp4)[height = 360][width = 640]' {link} -o '{out_1}.%(ext)s'

ffmpeg -i {out_1} -vn {out_2}.wav

sox {out_2} {out_3} channels 1 rate 16000

pocketsphinx_continuous -infile {out_3} -samprate 16000 -hmm {ACOUSTICMODEL} -dict {DICTIONARY} -lm {LANGMODEL} -fwdflat yes -bestpath yes 2> error.log | tee {out_4}.log && rm error.log
```

Note that there's an extra ffmpeg step to extract the audio, instead of simply directly downloading it with youtube-dl because video is needed as well.

Everything works correctly as far as I can tell, but I've never really dealt with audio before so I'm not sure if this is the best way to go about it.

Comment: Why is the video needed as well?

Comment: Need videos for object recognition in a different part of the project. But for my task specifically, only audio is needed.

Comment: You don't want to use `youtube-dl` to download any existing subtitles (including the auto generated ones on YT)? See *Subtitle Options* in the manual. It can also convert the audio to WAV. See *Post-processing Options*. If you still want to use `ffmpeg` then you can omit `sox` if you add `-ar 16000` and `-ac 1` to the `ffmpeg` command. `pocketsphinx_continuous` doesn't seem to accept pipes, but if you can use a named pipe (see `mkfifo`) if you don't want to create a temporary WAV file. Worth a try. I don't know if PS will like it.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I'll try and see if youtube auto generated subtitles are better than pocketsphinx's